# KML styling without styleUrl

Tags: css, xml, kml, google-earth

Is there a way to color eg. a placemark without using styleUrl's?
What i want to do is to style a placemark directly inside the placemark, instead of having to declare a style-id and referring to that id in the placemark.

I imagined something like:

```
<Folder>
  <name>Paths</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Extruded</name>
    <visibility>1</visibility>
    <LineString color="7f00ffff" width="2">
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <tessellate>0</tessellate>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>
        -112.2656634181359,36.09445214722695,2630
        -112.2652238941097,36.09520916122063,2630
        -112.2645079986395,36.09580763864907,2830
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
  </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. You simply have to add the style-tags inside the placemark but ***outside*** the object. I made the mistake prior to asking the question to, place the style-tage inside the linestring.

The code that satisfied my needs:

```
<Folder>
    <name>Paths</name>
    <Placemark>
        <Style>
            <LineStyle>
                <color>7f00ffff</color>
                <width>2</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <name>Extruded</name>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <LineString>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
            <tessellate>0</tessellate>
            <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                -112.2656634181359,36.09445214722695,2630
                -112.2652238941097,36.09520916122063,2630
                -112.2645079986395,36.09580763864907,2830
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```

Comment: Would mind editing your post and append the KML that did what you needed?

Comment: Style element inside placemark is called an inline style.